# '-' character in Docker compose file

Tags: docker, docker-compose, containers, dockerfile

The Docker compose file to create a MariaDB container is shown below:

```
version: '2'
services:
  mariadb:
    container_name: mytest
    image: 'mariadb:X.X.X'
    restart: always
    ports:
    - '3306:3306'
    environment:
    - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
```

My question is why we are using '**-**' for '*ports*' and '*environment*'. Is this only for readability purpose or it has some other importance also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is based on [YAML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML), the '-' is to start a list of elements, so you can have multiple ones.

Answer (score 0):

Because both ports and environment are YAML collections, since you can have multiple port mappings and environment variables.

Check [YAML - Collections](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2759963).